# When trying to access the file stored in the Alibaba Cloud OSS using internet endpoint it throws error

Tags: alibaba-cloud

when I am trying to access the file stored in Alibaba Cloud OSS using internet endpoint it shows error.

For instance, I like to access demo.jpg stored in the testbucket in Singapore region.

I issued the command like:

```
http://oss-ap-southeast-1.aliyuncs.com/testbucket/demo.jpg
```

Error:

```
 This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
    <Error>
    <Code>SecondLevelDomainForbidden</Code>
    <Message>
    The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using OSS third level domain.
    </Message>
    <RequestId>5C4F1FA099D9D60F934921C6</RequestId>
    <HostId>oss-ap-southeast-1.aliyuncs.com</HostId>
    </Error>
```

What I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buckets with an internal name are supposed to be accessed only from Alibaba Cloud internal resources.

Use case is: you have ECS instance and would like to copy object from OSS to ECS. You can use **internal** bucket endpoint and the network traffic fee will not be collected.

To summarize:

- internal buckets are for Alibaba Cloud internal resources only
- you don't pay for network traffic while using **internal** endpoints
  within Alibaba Cloud

[OSS Documentation](https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/31834.html)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try changing the bucket and object access level to public. This is to see if the error is due to permission issue or not